# What is the number under my Battle.Net StarCraft 2 profile name?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

What is this number?

[image: battle.net profile]

Thanks.

Comment: Two hundred and sixty.

Comment: Obviously the correct answer @Lee

Comment: @Lee hahaha I lol'd

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The number next to that shield is your "achievement points". You earn them based on the point values of various achievements you have completed. These achievements include the ones from single player as well as multiplayer. Go to the achievements tab of your profile for more information on the achievements you have and how to earns the ones you don't.

If you meant the number next to your username (which is not where the arrow appears to be pointing), that is your player identifier. It is used by battle.net to distinguish between players with the same player names.

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes before I could accept. But there you go. THanks.

Comment: @Carlo I never knew there was a limit...

Comment: I guess that's new cause I've never seen it in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7):

Achievement points!

These points are gained from doing certain tasks in the game, for example, "Find out what Matt Horner won playing poker."  This involves talking to characters in game.

Achievement Points are further broken down into categories so that people who prefer different parts of the game an accumulate them, and not feel as though they have to play JUST online multi or JUST the campaign.  These areas are as follows:

- Campaign -> Specific to the Single Player Campaign
- Exploration -> Specific to the Challenges
- Custom Games -> Which all must be done in Custom Games
- Cooperative -> Referring to Cooperative play vs the AI
- Quick Match -> Referring to ladder play
- Combat -> Which are across various game types

Additionally there is a category: "Feats of Strength."  This is a hold over from World of Warcraft which usually indicates achievements which can only be earned for a certain time period or by certain people.  Currently, most of the Feats of Strength should be available to all (though hot shot can be permanently missed), though there is no guarantee this will be true going forward.  Additionally, Feats of Strength do not affect your Achievement point total.

Each of these achievements has a point value associated with it which adds to your total number of points.

You can see the full list of achievements [here](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements)